# When to use laravel Queues

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I am developing a web application which will be exposing APIs to mobile application (android/iOS). As i know queues are meant to be used where there is a heavy duty API call going on , like an email/sms sending or order creation.

I am exposing the following APIs

- createproduct
- createuser
- createorder

If all of these are a function which will be defined in a Queue will it make sense? My idea is to deliver quick response back to the App so that it doesnt have to wait for the process to complete.Especially creating a product or order doesn't require the use to wait for long.

Does too much usage of queue worker will affect my application?

Comment: If you create a user/product/order shouldn't you be sending a response back to the application that contains the result of that operation? If you put the logic in queues that are being processed asynchronously, then you loose the ability to send back the result of the operation in the request response. Which means that the client won't know if an order was created successfully or not.

Comment: Got your point. So you mean, i should put all those 'not so important to know the response' kind of services like email or sms calls may be made as queue right?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Cool thanks for the clarification

Comment: In addition to @Bogdan recommendation, you can however split the process into two parts. Online part to create the DB record for example, so you can reply back to the client. Then create an event with the creation, and an event listener to perform the rest of the operation, send emails and SMS for example. Anything that can go offline.